# SQL to RAILS3 using Active records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Can any one help me to write this using rails3 active record query??

SQL-

```
SELECT DISTINCT `merchants`.id FROM `merchants` 
  INNER JOIN `merchant_status_assignments` ON `merchants`.`id` = `merchant_status_assignments`.`merchant_id` 
  INNER JOIN `merchant_statuses` ON `merchant_statuses`.`id` = `merchant_status_assignments`.`merchant_status_id` 
  INNER JOIN `merchant_status_assignments` `merchant_status_assignments_merchants` ON `merchant_status_assignments_merchants`.`merchant_id` = `merchants`.`id` 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN `favourite_merchants` ON `favourite_merchants`.`merchant_id` = `merchants`.`id` AND `favourite_merchants`.`customer_id` = 11
  WHERE `merchants`.`status` = 1 AND `merchant_statuses`.`name` = 'new_merchant' 
    AND (merchants.site_id = 1)
```

Comment: I tried this- To->> controller def new_list @merchants = Merchant.front_search(current_site.id, params).includes(:favourite_merchant).where(customer_id => current_customer.id) END TO->> MODEL def self.front_search(site_id, params) merchants = merchants.joins(:merchant_statuses , :merchant_status_assignments) .where("merchant_statuses.name" => params[:status]).select('DISTINCT merchants.*') END

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer

controller

def 
new_list @merchants = Merchant.front_search(current_site.id, params).includes(:favourite_merchant).where(customer_id => current_customer.id) 
END

MODEL

def
self.front_search(site_id, params) merchants = merchants.joins(:merchant_statuses , :merchant_status_assignments) .where("merchant_statuses.name" => params[:status]).select('DISTINCT merchants.*') 
END